# How to create 2 steps expandable tableview Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

[image]
There is a main table view and inside each of the main table view cell has their own header table view. Then each of the header table view cell has their own sub-header table view. All the table rows don't have fixed counts according to the dynamic data. What I try to achieve is when a cell of the main table view is expanded, I should see the header table view cells unexpanded. After a header table view cell is expended, I should see the sub-header table view. I need a solution without using libraries.

I provided the storyboard UI based on what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To deal with expandable cells (or cells inside cells effect) I recommend using UIStackView inside UITableViewCell and add inside needed views with data.

For example  you can create UIView inside Xib file and load it inside needed UITableViewCell then add to UIStackView and fill with data.

Then you can simply hide/unhide elements inside UIStackView to archive expanding/unxpanding.

This way or other you should use 1 UITableView.

Answer (score 1):

I once made a 1 step expandable Table View.

Here is what I did to achieve that.

Do not make different table views for each hierarchy. That will be difficult to manage. Instead, make one table view but change the type of cell you want to show. If the cell is top level cell or first level cell or the second level cell, change the design of each one that.

The data source will then have list of list of list to denote the 2 level expandable UITableView.

To open and close the table view, you can simply change the data source and reload or use `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates`